# ['UnboundLocalError', ["local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"]]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to call the function  in other program getting the error like:

```
[\'UnboundLocalError\', ["local variable \'x\' referenced before assignment"]]
```

please help

```
connect FSN1 @FSN1 @MANTISPORT  
connect FSN2 @FSN2 @MANTISPORT  
* from commonFunctions import *  
* import os  
* import sys  
* import shutil
import io

*:
    #********* Common Variables**********
    exactShareNameFound = False

    def findExact(logMessage, share):
        f = open('logFile', 'w+')
        f.write(logMessage)
        for line in f:

          if line.find('%s')%(share) >= 0: exactShareNameFound = True

          if exactShareNameFound: x+= line

          if line.find('Share Name')>=0:
              if line.find('%s')(share)<0: exactShareNameFound = False

              else:
                    print('ERROR!!')
          else:
                print('Error in Executing Loop')



        return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is manipulating a variable `x` without ever setting it first:

```
if exactShareNameFound: x+= line
```

Add the following line at the top of the function:

```
x = ''
```

The code will not work as currently written *anyway* because it attempts to read from a file opened in 'write and read' mode; the file pointer is set to the *end* of the file and thus reading from it will never return data without seeking to the strat first.

The function could do with some more cleaning up:

```
def findExact(logMessage, share):
    share = str(share)

    with open('logFile', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(logMessage)
        f.seek(0)

        lines = []
        found = False
        for line in f:
            if share in line:
                found = True

            if found: 
                x.append(line)

            if 'Share Name' in line:
                if share not in line:
                    found = False
                    continue

    return ''.join(lines)
```

It is unclear to me when 'ERROR' messages should be raised; use `raise ValueError('error message')` instead of loud 'print' statements to exit the function early in any case.

Answer (score 1):

In python and almost all other programming languages, you cannot change the value in a variable unless you declare it.

in your code:

`if exactShareNameFound: x+= line`

you did not declare x, but you are referring to it in the above line.

If you wanted to append the value of `line` to `x`, then declare a variable `x` before using it, like so:

```
x = ''
```